# Get BufferedImage from png PDXObjectImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, pdfbox

I'm trying to get a BufferedImage from PDXObjectImage that has png suffix with:

```
PDResources pdResources = pdPage.getResources();
Map<String, PDXObject> xobjects = (Map<String, PDXObject>) pdResources.getXObjects();
if (xobjects != null) {
    for (String key : xobjects.keySet()) {
        PDXObject xobject = xobjects.get(key);
        if (xobject instanceof PDXObjectImage) {
            PDXObjectImage imageObject = (PDXObjectImage) xobject;
            String suffix = imageObject.getSuffix();
            if (suffix != null) {
                BufferedImage image = imageObject.getRGBImage();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code works fine having jpg PDXObjectImages but image is null with png images.

What is the right way to get a BufferedImage from a PDXObjectImage that has PNG suffix?

I also tried :

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(((PDPixelMap)imageObject).getPDStream().createInputStream());
```

But again image is null.

I'm using org.apache.pdfbox version 1.8.11.

Comment: If you get any log messages? Maybe you have to install the jbig2 decoder. Btw the latest version is 2.0.2.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I don't get any errors or warnings, imageObject.getRGBImage() just returns null.

Comment: Then please share the PDF.

Comment: Just make sure you have JAI plugins that can decompress that image and keep using getRGBImage(). BTW, it would help a lot if you could upload the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally moved to version 2.0 of PDFBox then got a clear warning that I have not installed jbig2 decoder and solved the problem adding the following dependency in maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.levigo.jbig2</groupId>
    <artifactId>levigo-jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

@TilmanHausherr thanks.